# jxBrowser is not working

Tags: java, browser, jxbrowser

I have jxBrowser in my project but no longer it works. I changed somewhere in project JDK possibly? I upgraded JDK version to 1.8 and version of licensed jxBrowser 4.2 for linux win mac platforms and project will work on win. Is it possible jxBrowser does not working on 1.8 JDK ?  (NetBeans IDE 8.0.2)

*Thanks for your help,
Sincerely.*

Answer (score 1):

JxBrowser [supports](http://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/system-requirements) JDK 1.8. I don't think it's the issue. I suppose the reason is probably in the license you have. Maybe you use evaluation license that is already expired. Please post the error message you seen when you run your app.

Comment: Which version of jxbrowser supports 1.8 JDK?

Comment: JxBrowser supports JDK 1.8 since version 5.0. If you use JDK 1.8 on Windows 10, then I recommend that you use JxBrowser 5.4.3. You can download 5.4.3 from https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser